# Sharing a specific database from phpmyadmin (cpanel)

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a cpanel account and have multiple database in the phpmyadmin of that account. I only want my developer to access and view only one specific database.

Will this be possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here: How to grant remote access to a single MySQL database

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1269/2180/how-to-grant-remote-access-to-a-single-mysql-database

Answer (score 2):

No, You can not directly access phpmyadmin without cPanel login details and due to that you can not access specific databases with phpmyadmin.